How to generate a user-defined array of numbers on a given interval a certain number of times
I need to generate user-defined integers as a required unordered set of numbers for a given interval, e.g. (10) a certain number of times, e.g. 3 in one column of a table.
The number and repetition of digits can be different and can be set by the user at his discretion.
For example, the desired result from top to bottom should look like this:
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2. 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2. 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2. 1, 0.

Perhaps, using the function
SELECT n
 FROM generate_series(ARRAY[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2. 1, 0], 3) n

or something similar?

You almost have it. You need to use unnest to split up the array, then cross join it with 3 rows from generate_series.
SELECT a.value
FROM unnest(
  ARRAY[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
) WITH ORDINALITY a(value, ordinal)
CROSS JOIN GENERATE_SERIES(1, 3) n(value)
ORDER BY
  n.value,
  a.ordinal;

db<>fiddle

It looks a bit ambiguous to me, i.e. in your first query without ORDER BY, generate_series() from 1 to 10 behaves as expected, but from 11- onwards it behaves unexpectedly....

Ordering is always ambiguous unless you specify an ORDER BY clause, there is never a guarantee what order you get your data without that. You didn't ask for ordering so I didn't add it. I've now edited that in.
